# にで and でに confusion

Tags: particles, particle-に, て-form, particle-で, copula

So I saw these particles in a definition and a song.

First, as ひとりでに, which got translated as by itself (this got approved by the way) and then "単独にでなく", which I'm guessing means not being done in/by independence/singleness (I don't know the word 単独 by the way I searched up it's Japanese and English definition). What do these words mean?

Comment: I’m not sure the で in ひとりでに is a particle. I’ve always thought it is 手 though I’m not completely sure it’s etymologically correct. The latter is 「単独に」で（は）なく.

Comment: @aguijonazo Oh, I never thought it can be 手. Do you have any reason to think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ひとりでに is a lexicalized adverb which has its own entry in dictionaries:

- jisho.org: https://jisho.org/word/%E7%8B%AC%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB
- デジタル大辞泉: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB/

You'll basically have to remember ひとりでに as a non-divisible fixed expression, and go on. The same is true with some fixed rentaishi such as 大きな; you have to remember this because it doesn't follow the basic conjugation pattern of i-adjectives.

単独にでなく is made of three words, and can be straightforwardly analyzed by the standard grammar:

- **単独に**: individually; in isolation; separately
- **で**: (continuative form of the copula だ)
- **なく**: not

So it just means "not individually", "not in an isolated manner", etc.

Comment: thanks!! i really appreciate it